# SVN-difference between lock on working copy of file and lock on repository file

Tags: svn, locking

What is the difference if I lock the file in the working copy that I have downloaded and the same file in the repository. The syntax is :

```
svn lock TARGET
```

So target can be URL for the file in repository and file in the working copy.

What is the difference in both ways?

Answer (score 1):

Locking a file through the `svn lock` command will always lock it in the repository.

If you use the 'file in your working copy' syntax (e.g. `svn lock readme.txt`), then you can only commit that file from that particular working copy.

If you use the 'URL in repository' syntax (`svn lock http://myrepo/svn/myproject/readme.txt`), changes to that file can not be committed from any working copy until the lock is removed.

For more information, see the svn book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html